# Mars at its closest is only a few light minutes away -- are different experiments performed when this happens?

Tags: mars, communication, robotics

While 3 minutes is not exactly real time, it still seems like remotely-controlled experiments of a different nature can be performed that could not be when Mars is farther.

Is this correct, that the experiments change when the two planets are closer?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Rover technology has evolved a lot since the 1960's and 70's!

- [How did Lunokhod 1 become "lost" in 1971; in what ways did astronomers "look for it" after that?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33786/12102)
- [What was it actually like driving the Lunokhod lunar rovers live from the ground? What were some of the biggest challenges?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54625/12102)
- [How (the heck) did Lunokhod 2 drive, navigate and survive a ~40 kilometer drive over four months on the Moon using 1970's technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54610/12102)
- [Official source discussing the stress that Lunokhod operators were experiencing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55605/12102)
- [How did Lunokhod 1 become "lost" in 1971; in what ways did astronomers "look for it" after that?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33786/12102)
- and especially [Were the Lunokhod Lunar rovers remote controlled in real time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4993/12102)

[image]

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4997/12102):

> The [Lunokhods](http://books.google.nl/books?id=4sIiQdFo0RMC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=lunokhod%20control&source=bl&ots=tzSf07rWCV&sig=1eMYiKMfpwApDLXTvZ4jbDLUrbM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zGvFU5fkBcG00QX1zYHQDg&ved=0CIYBEOgBMBI#v=onepage&q=lunokhod%20control&f=false) were [controlled in real-time from Earth](http://www.airspacemag.com/space/the-other-moon-landings-6457729/?all) (long article well worth reading), exactly as you say. A camera relayed images to Earth (one image every 7-20 seconds) and a five-man team (driver, commander, navigator, radio antenna operator, and the flight engineer) would control the rover.

Lunokhod were driven life by beings on Earth, and Apollo LRV's were driven by beings on the Moon.

All of the robotic Mars and Lunar rovers and landers *since then* have had computers with memory, and received instruction sets that they executed afterwards.

***That doesn't mean*** that there have never been situations where instructions have been sent and results received followed by more instructions in near-real time! But the idea has always been to avoid that.

(I think there's a possible new question there)

Certainly there will be engineers (as well as us as home) sitting on the edges of their seats watching things happen in the early hours and days after landing, but to minimize risk these activities are all either pre-programmed, or downloaded in bulk after landing.

I think there is an answer somewhere on the site about new software being downloaded to a Mars rover once it lands, but I can't find it yet.

Instead, here are some related posts:

- [What was the first unplanned "over-the-air" software update of a spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40547/12102)
- [What was NASA's "Hack" to improve Opportunity's memory in 2015? Did it help?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27868/12102)
- [How many memory banks does Opportunity have?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27878/12102)
- [How much can the Mars rover Curiosity do autonomously, after four years of operation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18222/12102)
- ["New Horizons' capabilities augmented by uploading new observing and onboard data-reduction software." How? What augmentations are begin considered?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51683/12102)
- [How much space could be freed up on New Horizons "once the spacecraft's flyby software is no longer needed"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51684/12102)
- [What was NASA's "Hack" to improve Opportunity's memory in 2015? Did it help?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27868/12102)

---

[image: All Mars and lunar rovers ranked by how far they've driven. Credit: Bob Al-Greene / Mashable]

> All Mars and lunar rovers ranked by how far they've driven. Credit: Bob Al-Greene / Mashable

> Sources of data: NASA, JPL-Caltech, GSFC, Arizona State University, China National Space Administration

From [How (the heck) did Lunokhod 2 drive, navigate and survive a ~40 kilometer drive over four months on the Moon using 1970's technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54610/12102)

Comment: Thanks. An aside: I think what these landings on planets and moons and flybys of the outer planets and their moons would have meant to men like Galileo who could never have imagined that within the span of less than half a dozen lifetimes the bodies he saw in a telescope would not only be visited by machines but by humans in person. Or maybe Galileo did imagine it.

Comment: @releseabe interesting perspective!